# question on Ideal and kernel of ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

In dummit and foote on page 243: If $I$ is the kernel of some ring homomorphism $\phi:R\to S$ the book showed that kernel is an ideal by arguing multiplication of left cosets under addition $R/I$ is well defined by properties of $\phi$ which I guess sure

but if I understood the definition of ideal correctly, can I not just argue that kernel of ring homomorphism is a subring of $R$ and closed under left and right multiplication by elements of $R$? Would this argument be valid ?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean to show the kernel is a subgroup of R (if it is a subring of R, then it has the identity, but then the absorption property forces it to be all of R) + closed under multiplication. And yes, that is exactly right and an easy way to show this.

Comment: @algebroo thanks! I think your comment made me realize why the book did it that way.  If I want use my argument I need to split into cases where ring contains 1 and do not contains 1?

Comment: not exactly. Remember that by definition, an ideal is a subgroup (not a subring) that is absorptive under multiplication by elements of the ring.